# Bigger Twitter user profile image

Tags: twitter

I'm developing an app that displays users' tweets along with their image. But the image being displayed is very small. I want the image (usual 128*128) one that is usually displayed on their profiles. Here's my relevant code:

```
foreach($ret1->results as $x)
{
     echo "<div class='ttl'><div class='ttlpadding'><div class='item'><a href=\"","http://www.twitter.com/".$x->from_user,"\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"",$x->profile_image_url,"\" title=\"", $x->from_user." (".$x->from_user_name.")", "\" /></a>\n";

    $text = preg_replace('/\s+#(\w+)/',' <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$1">#$1</a>', $x->text);
    echo "<div class='clr'></div>";
    echo "<div class='tweet'>".$text."</div></div></div></div><div class='clrflt'></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

`substr($x->profile_image_url,[index-start],strlen($x->profile_image_url)[index-end]).'jpg'`

This will return the original images uploaded by the users.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching big images

call

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/username.json?size=original
```

Replace username by the twitter handle