# Fetching bigger images of Twitter users

Tags: twitter

I'm developing an app that displays users' tweets along with their image. But the image being displayed is very small. I want the image (usual 128*128) one that is usually displayed on their profiles to be shown instead f the small one. I'm using **JSON**. Here's my relevant code:

```
...
...    
$url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=".$qe."&geocode=".$geo."&rpp=10";
...
...
foreach($ret1->results as $x)
    {
         echo "<div class='ttl'><div class='ttlpadding'><div class='item'><a href=\"","http://www.twitter.com/".$x->from_user,"\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"",$x->profile_image_url,"\" title=\"", $x->from_user." (".$x->from_user_name.")", "\" /></a>\n";

        $text = preg_replace('/\s+#(\w+)/',' <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$1">#$1</a>', $x->text);
        echo "<div class='clr'></div>";
        echo "<div class='tweet'>".$text."</div></div></div></div><div class='clrflt'></div>";
    }
```

Comment: have edited the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching big images

call

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/username.json?size=original
```

Replace username by the twitter handle

The [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/:screen_name) about getting profile images

Similar stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013920/bigger-twitter-user-profile-image). Avoid Reposting questions.